# How to select a column of data from table with WHERE closure and display

Tags: yii-extensions, yii, yii-components

How to **select** a column of data from table with **WHERE** closure and list as combo-box in yii?

Comment: do you mean retrieve a set of models from a table in your database to list in a dropdown box?

Comment: ya,am MVC&yii beginner, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the CHtml methods [dropDownList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail) and [activeDropDownList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail).

You can set the data you insert into the dropdownlist to be the results from an active record query, for example;

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('myDropdown', '1',  CHtml::listData(myModel::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('myField'=>1)),'id','name'));
```

The above command would select all the results from the `myModel` model where `myField = 1` (using their 'id' as the value and their 'name' as the displayed text)  and insert them into a dropdownlist with name 'myDropdown' and the initial selected value would be 1.

If you're using this in a form, for example created by gii, then you can use the $form to create the dropdown. This actually uses activeDropDownList(), so the syntax is a little different, here's an example:

```
 echo $form->dropDownList($model,'myOtherField', CHtml::listData(myModel::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('myField'=>1)),'id','name'));
```

the bit that's actually populating the dropdownlist with the data from the active record query is the [CHtml::listData()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) method which is taking a result set from the active record query and formatting it into an array that will be accepted into the `$data` param in dropDownList() or activeDropDownList().